# How to protected the Sitemap.xml file from frequent access?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, security, iis

Our sitemap.xml file is becoming large. I'd like to prevent randoms from accessing the Sitemap.xml file and only allow google, yahoo and bing to access it. Kinda like a whitelist approach. Where can I find the IP addresses of search engine sitemap crawlers?

Comment: Why? There should be nothing in your sitemap file that isn't public, so what difference does it make who accesses it?

Answer (score 0):

You're better off doing the filtering by user agent. You can search for the ones you want to allow [here](http://www.user-agents.org/free-search.shtml).

Comment: filtering based on User-Agent is a bad-idea as anyone can forge an HTTP Request with a fake User-Agent of allowed values and fetch the blocked resource.